# Как тестировать динамичные 3D объекты на сайте

Tags: тестирование, 3d, jstree

Есть динамичная 3D модель (пол, стены) на tree js наподобие этих https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/ru/threejs-primitives.html

Через html код (F12-Elements) не достучаться, код не видит фигуры. 
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как можно автотестами протестировать наличие этой фигуры, смену текстур и тд. До этого немного изучала Selenium, но всё сводилось к Console командам в браузере, т.е. я всё могла "прощупать" через html код страницы